# Creating a User Account on Dynamics CRM from PHP using SOAP client

Tags: php, soap, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am writing a PHP code that will create a User Account on Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4 API using the SOAP client. In API's fieldset there are many types of fields among the required fields (strings, boolean, lookup and picklist). So I'm sending the request with values for these fields. All the fields are handling by CRM server except those fields which's types are "picklist". They are coming to server blank. I can't find out why. Please help with syntax and etc. to create a user on CRM containing a picklist type field.

Comment: Avik jan, can you put your codes so we can help you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the Picklist class when setting your attribute?

E.g (Taken from [Microsoft Forums](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crmdevelopment/thread/3b531c4c-ba86-4298-baa8-6698047232a1)):

```
DynamicEntity entity = new DynamicEntitty("name of your entity");
entity["picklist field"] = new Picklist(<integer value of picklist>);
```